# Accessing the Router.history property in React routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have routes defined as following:

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={MainView}>
        <IndexRoute component={SearchBarMainView} />
        <Route path="search/:keyword" component={SearchResultsMainView}/>
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

How do I access Router's history property from a component? I need that for using `history.push(url)` - whether I use `hashHistory` or `browserHistory` - in other words I want my app to be history type agnostic and use the history object provided to the router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the component in a [`withRouter`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.0/docs/API.md#withroutercomponent-options) higher-order component. That will inject a `router` prop into your component, which you can use to navigate.